# i want download files with python using wget(FTP). but error occured. please help to download

Tags: python-3.x, url, download, ftp, wget

I want down load "*_ice.nc" files in ftp. so..

library

```
import wget
import math
import re 
from urllib import request
```

adress and file list

```
url = "ftp://ftp.hycom.org/datasets/GLBy0.08/expt_93.0/data/hindcasts/2021/" #url
html = request.urlopen(url) #open url
html_contents = str(html.read().decode("cp949"))
url_list = re.findall(r"(ftp)(.+)(_ice.nc)", html_contents)
```

loop for download

```
for url in url_list: #loop 
    url_full="".join(url) #tuple to string
    file_name=url_full.split("/")[-1]
    print('\nDownloading ' + file_name) 
    wget.download(url_full) #down with wget
```

but error messege occured like this
(ValueError: unknown url type: 'ftp%20%20%20%20%20%20ftp%20%20%20%20%20%20382663848%20Jan%2002%20%202021%20hycom_GLBy0.08_930_2021010112_t000_ice.nc')

could i get some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After decoding

```
ftp%20%20%20%20%20%20ftp%20%20%20%20%20%20382663848%20Jan%2002%20%202021%20hycom_GLBy0.08_930_2021010112_t000_ice.nc
```

is

```
ftp      ftp      382663848 Jan 02  2021 hycom_GLBy0.08_930_2021010112_t000_ice.nc
```

which clearly is not legal `ftp` address. You need alter your code so it will be

```
ftp://ftp.hycom.org/datasets/GLBy0.08/expt_93.0/data/hindcasts/2021/hycom_GLBy0.08_930_2021010112_t000_ice.nc
```

I suggest temporarily replacing `wget.download(url_full)` using `print(url_full)`, then apply changes to get desired output and then reverting to `wget.download(url_full)`.